# SSE: Counter in a loop

Tags: c++, loops, sse

I'm converting [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/97766) Mathematica sources by user "J. M. ain't a mathematician" to C++ and also support SIMD (SSE2 -->). So far I've got C++ code done. Here's the sine version on [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/b9Pj5MEfK) .

I (as in noobie regarding SSE) have not managed to solve this yet and having troubles when trying to control which elements are calculated in a while loop. Here's my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <cstdint>


 // simple version 
float pade_sine(float x){  
 float f=0.25f;  
 float z=x*0.5f;  
    int k=0;  
    while (std::abs(z)>f){  
        z*=0.5f;  
        k++;  
        }  
    float z2=std::pow(z,2.0f);  
    float r=z*(1.0f+(z2/105.0f-1.0f)*std::pow(z/3.0f,2.0f))/  
          (1.0f+(z2/7.0f-4.0f)*std::pow(z/3.0f,2.0f));  
    while(k > 0){  
        r = (2.0f*r)/(1.0f-r*r);  
        k--;
    } 
    return (2.0f*r)/(1.0f+r*r);  
}  

__m128 sincos_sse(__m128 x, __m128 f, bool sine, int maxloops) {

const __m128 c1 = _mm_set1_ps(105.0f);
const __m128 c2 = _mm_set1_ps(3.0f);
const __m128 c3 = _mm_set1_ps(7.0f);
const __m128 zero = _mm_set1_ps(0.0f);
const __m128 half = _mm_set1_ps(0.5f);
const __m128 one = _mm_set1_ps(1.0f);
const __m128 two = _mm_set1_ps(2.0f);
const __m128 four = _mm_set1_ps(4.0f);
const __m128 signmask = half; //_mm_set1_ps(-1.0f);

int k = 0;
int mask, oldmask = 0;
    __m128  z  = _mm_mul_ps(x, half);
    __m128  flags, abs_z;
    __m128 kvec;

    // repeat halving           
    while (k < maxloops) {
                
        abs_z = _mm_max_ps(_mm_sub_ps(_mm_setzero_ps(), z), z);
        // make flag either 0 or 0.5 (this value is used as a multiplier later)
        flags = _mm_cmpgt_ps(abs_z, f);  
        flags = _mm_mul_ps(_mm_and_ps(flags, signmask), one);
        // calculate k for each element
        kvec = _mm_add_ps(kvec,_mm_mul_ps(_mm_and_ps(flags, signmask), two));  
        // get mask value to control the loop
        mask = _mm_movemask_epi8((__m128i)abs_z);
        // break loop if         
        if( mask == oldmask){
            //k--;
            //kvec = _mm_sub_ps(kvec, _mm_and_ps(_mm_cmpgt_ps(kvec, half), one));
            break;
        }
        oldmask = mask;
        k++;
        // calculate new z values by flags
        z  = _mm_sub_ps(z, _mm_mul_ps(z, flags));
    }

    __m128  z2 = _mm_mul_ps(z, z);
    __m128  t  = _mm_div_ps(z, c2);
    __m128  p  = _mm_mul_ps(t, t);
            t  = _mm_div_ps(z2, c1);
            p  = _mm_mul_ps(p, _mm_sub_ps(t, one));
            p  = _mm_add_ps(one, p);
            p  = _mm_mul_ps(z, p);
            t  = _mm_div_ps(z, c2);
    __m128  q  = _mm_mul_ps(t, t); 
            t  = _mm_div_ps(z2, c3);
            q  = _mm_mul_ps(q, _mm_sub_ps(t, four));
            q  = _mm_add_ps(q, one);
        
    __m128  r  = _mm_div_ps(p, q);


    // double-angle identity
    __m128 tmp = zero;
    __m128 multipliers;
        while (k){
            multipliers = _mm_and_ps(_mm_cmpgt_ps(kvec, half), one);
            tmp = _mm_mul_ps(_mm_div_ps(_mm_mul_ps(two, r), _mm_sub_ps(one, _mm_mul_ps(r,r))), multipliers);
            r = _mm_add_ps(r, tmp);
            --k;
            kvec = _mm_sub_ps(kvec, multipliers);
        }

        if (sine){
            return _mm_div_ps(_mm_mul_ps(two, r), _mm_add_ps(one, _mm_mul_ps(r,r)));
        }
        return _mm_div_ps(_mm_sub_ps(one, _mm_mul_ps(r, r)), _mm_add_ps(one, _mm_mul_ps(r,r)));
}

int main() {
    
    bool sine = true;
    float res[4] = { 0 };
    
    float in = 0.5;
    if (std::abs(in) > M_PI/2.0){ sine = false;}
    
    __m128 x = _mm_set_ps(in, 1.01f, -0.23f, 0.99f);
    __m128 f = _mm_set1_ps(0.25f);

    _mm_storeu_ps(res, sincos_sse(x, f, sine, 10));

    std::cout << "\n\nsincos_sse  = " << res[3] << "  " << res[2] << "  " << res[1] << "  "<< res[0] << "  " << std::endl;    
    std::cout << "std::sin    = " << std::sin(x[3]) << "  " << std::sin(x[2]) << "  "<< std::sin(x[1]) << "  "<< std::sin(x[0]) << "  " << std::endl;
    
    for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--){
        if (sine){
            std::cout << "std::sin       = " << std::sin(x[i]) << std::endl;
            std::cout << "std::sin <> sincos_sse " << std::sin(x[i]) - res[i]<< std::endl;
        }
        else{
            std::cout << "std::cos       = " << std::cos(x[i]) << std::endl;
            std::cout << "std::cos <> sincos_sse " << std::cos(x[i]) - res[i]<< std::endl;
        }

    }
    
   
}
```

Online at https://godbolt.org/z/T5r1xPv8f

My non-SSE code uses variable ***k*** to control the *double-angle identity* loop but, in SSE implementation one needs to know ***k*** for each element (which is/can be solved in *repeat halving* loop).

I think the issue is following and is located in double-angle identity loop:

EDIT:
Lets say f = 0.25 and the input vector *x* to be calculated is

{0.5, 1.01, -0.23, 0.99}

X values are halved before loop.
After repeat halving loop (where all x[n] > f[n] elements are halved as many times as needed to get  x[n] <= f[n]), *k*'s (in *kvec*) for *x* vector elements are:

{0, 2, 0, 1}

so, in double-angle identity loop, one element needs to pass the calculation twice, one element once and rest two jumps over.

Loop control is handled by *kvec* so that *kvec* value decreases by one after each loop. *kvec* value (1 or 0) is used as a multiplier in calculation.

Problem is how to sum the values in loop because of loop is executed by highest *k* value (twice in this example case) when the *kvec* related values (i.e. *multipliers* 1 or 0) are in each round as:

1. {0 1 0 1}
2. {0 1 0 0}
3. {0 0 0 0}

i.e. last *kvec* element zeroes the result in 2nd calculation round and 2nd element does it too if we go to 3rd round. So, I would need to get that values saved before it is zeroed. I do it now by summing the values but that is done wrongly because of the result is wrong. If _mm_max_ps() is used the result is OK for positive input values but for negative it is -0.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You're already using `_mm_cmpgt_ps` / `_mm_and_ps` to prepare a 0 or 0.5 value.  You can do the same with integer compares if necessary, and maybe a full blend using `and`/`andnot`/`or` to make a divisor with value `1.0` vs. something else.  `kvec = _mm_sub_epi32(kvec, cmp_result)` can count per-element `k` values, using the `0` / `0xFFFFFFFF` compare result as a `0` / `-1` integer.

Comment: Or can you make that part non-looping, like doing some integer stuff on the FP bit-patterns to figure what 2^-n to multiply by?  (Like subtract their exponent fields and use that as an offset from `1.0`?  Perhaps you then need one more conditional iteration to account for mantissa differences.)  Also surely you can at least avoid doing the absolute value each time through the loop, just recording signs once to re-apply later.  (`abs` is just `_mm_andnot_ps(v, _mm_set1_ps(-0.0f))` to clear the sign bit).

Comment: Thanks for the fast comments. I was not sure if cmpgt/and could work in this control loop. Have to try now.

Comment: For vectorized sincos, you might want to take a look at https://github.com/vectorclass/version2/blob/master/vectormath_trig.h (Apache license).  After range-reduction, they just use a Taylor expansion over the -pi/4 .. +pi/4 range and some blending based on quadrant.  As you've realized, iterating sucks for SIMD because all elements pay for the worst-case element, and branching on SIMD compares is a bit less efficient than scalar FP.  IDK if your function has precision advantages that might make it worthwhile; if not, it's a learning exercise to see how it could be done.

Comment: Yes, this is not a fast method but, it's different from those well known approximations here and there. See what I mean: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97560/numerically-efficient-approximation-of-coss/97601#97601 (also, scroll the thread there to its end direction) . And, of course, also a learning exercise for me to translate it to SSE.

Comment: Quite close now but, something I don't understand on how to calculate in a loop  (may be a simple matter in question but, my brains are soon locked). - https://godbolt.org/z/z1KreWsjj

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing with FP math for `kvec`.  It looks like an insane amount of ANDing and multiply with constants when you could be using `__m128i kvec = _mm_setzero_si128()` and `kvec = _mm_sub_epi32(kvec, _mm_castps_si128(cmpps_result))` to get an integer count.  Does your actual `kvec` calculation do something other than count the number of times each element of the initial `flags` was true?  Also you have a constant called `signmask` which I was expecting to be `0x80000000` or `0x7fffffff` (`-0.0f` or its inverse) but instead is `0.5f` for no apparent reason.

Comment: Also, `_mm_movemask_epi8` on FP bit-patterns?  Is that grabbing one of the exponent bits as well as the sign?  No comment explains why you're doing that.

Comment: This may sound complicated but I'll try explain. **movemask** takes the _mask_ value and is used for to break the loop execution when equal with previous value (_oldmask_). **kvec** holds the sum of _k_'s for each element and it is then used latter to control loop calculation as a multiplier 1 or 0 (each loop pass decreases _kvec_ values by one until all are zeros and the calculation is done). **signmask** is a mask and also a halving multiplier (0.5f). My guess was that this may save few code lines when done this way. Maybe naming constants/variables could be better. Hope this info helped.

Comment: Yeah, I can see *what* the code is doing (comparing with `oldmask`) but it's not obvious *why*, specifically what the high-level significance is of a bit changing in the `_mm_movemask_epi8` (high bit of every byte) result that you wouldn't get with `_mm_movemask_ps` (high bit of every 32-bit element), the natural choice for a `_mm_cmpgt_ps` result.  And if you just want to increment `kvec` by one, why not `_mm_add_ps(kvec, _mm_and_ps(flags, one))`.  Or much better, make kvec an integer vector and treat the `_mm_cmpgt_ps` result bit-pattern as an integer 0 or -1 like I suggested originally.

Comment: Oops, you're only using the compare result `flags` to update `kvec`, not as part of branching?  That's on `abs_z`.  So you must be looking at some exponent or mantissa bits I guess, but no comment explains which one or its significance.  Also, saving source lines is not a relevant consideration.  Saving asm instructions is the goal when optimizing.  (And keeping loop-carried dependency chains short.)  You can mask `flags` two different ways, with `0.5` and with `1.0` if you want differently-scaled versions.

Comment: So `_mm_movemask_epi8` is actually checking if the low bit of the exponent changed in `abs_z` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format).  (Or bit #7 or #15 bits in the mantissa but scaling by a power of 2 won't change those unless it becomes subnormal).  Why is the low bit of the exponent an interesting condition to break on?  Your debug prints of `mask` would be more useful in hex. And debug-printing each vector on one line would be easier to follow.

Comment: Also, won't `z` become `0.0` for most elements by the time you leave the loop, since `flags` will be all-zero in some elements. Perhaps you want to `flags` to be either `0.5` or `1.0` according to the compare result, so values stay unchanged once their compare becomes false? Normally you'd `_mm_or_ps( and(cmp, half), andnot(cmp, one))` but the bit-patterns are related (https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html). 1.0 has an exponent of `0b01111111` while 0.5 has `0b01111110` (low bit cleared). `_mm_or_ps(one, _mm_andnot_ps(cmp, _mm_castsi128_ps(_mm_set1_epi32(1<<23))));` - two insns

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/crdGKGYE1 makes that change to scale by 1.0 or 0.5, and using `__m128i kvec`.  IDK if the result is useful; I think it's mostly still doing the same stuff your code was doing, but I don't have time to look at it more.  I also changed the printing to output 4 elements of a vector on the same line, with tabs between elements.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check your suggestions. The _f_ input parameter and input values has impact on how many times loops are done. Issue I'm still having is in calculations done inside the loop(s). I have to debug values between non-SSE and SSE implementations to be sure where those goes differently. IIRC, I found that _mm_movemask_epi8 technique from these forums and changing it to FP version did not work. Original non-SSE code for sine approximation: https://godbolt.org/z/b9Pj5MEfK

Comment: That code makes a ton more sense; the loop condition is based on `std::abs(z)>f`, not the raw exponent bits of `abs(z)` itself, and nothing about a change from the previous iteration.  You're already doing that compare with SIMD, so `mask = _mm_movemask_ps(cmpgt_result)` would give you an integer bitmap of the compare result, which you can check for being all-zero (or for == 0x0f to check that it was true for elements if you wanted.).  You should include the scalar original in your question to show people what you're trying to vectorize. (Also the math.SE link)

Comment: Re: z=0 because you make the multiplier `0`: don't do that.  Make the multiplier `0.5` or `1.0`.   `0.0` is the identity element for addition and subtraction, `1.0` is the identity element for multiplication and division.  I [commented yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77648631/sse-counter-in-a-loop#comment136901604_77648631) with a simple way and a fun way to do that, in 2 instructions instead of 3.  (Not counting `movaps` register copies, which are probably similar between the two.)

Comment: OK, I'll look it closer. By your edited version from yesterday, all resulted 0 so I was not sure if the suggested change worked as expected.

Comment: Oh, I was ORing into the wrong constant, `one` which already has all the low exponent bits set, rather than `half`.  I didn't have time to look at the output much yesterday, especially since the `oldmask == mask` from `movmemask_epi8(abs_z)` as a loop condition still makes zero sense.  The vector version of your scalar loop condition is `mask = _mm_movemask_ps(flags)`, and check it for being all zero.  https://godbolt.org/z/Y6znYoYqz produces correct `scale_half_or_one` and `kvec` values.

Comment: Just realized you were doing `z = z - flags*z`, edited the Godbolt link in my last comment to just do `z = z*scale_half_or_one`.  `sub(z, mul(z, scale))` might have worked with 0 or 0.5, even with positive or negative `z`, but `orps` is cheaper than `subps` (especially for latency) so it's better to spend 1 extra instruction making a `1.0` or `0.5` constant.  That's also why my buggy initial version was giving z=0 instead of z unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

After good sleep I had an answer in mind to get the function work correctly. What was needed was just to make all calculations done through positive input values. So had to take signs of input values and then restore them before final calculation. This answer is based on my own code given in question but, I do make changes @PeterCordes suggested to get the performance improved.
I have not yet tested if performance is worse or better compared to std library functions.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <cstdint>

__m128 sincos_sse(__m128 x, __m128 f, bool sine, int maxloops) {

const __m128 c1 = _mm_set1_ps(105.0f);
const __m128 c2 = _mm_set1_ps(3.0f);
const __m128 c3 = _mm_set1_ps(7.0f);
const __m128 zero = _mm_set1_ps(0.0f);
const __m128 half = _mm_set1_ps(0.5f);
const __m128 one = _mm_set1_ps(1.0f);
const __m128 two = _mm_set1_ps(2.0f);
const __m128 four = _mm_set1_ps(4.0f);
const __m128 multipliermask = half;

const __m128 signmask = _mm_set1_ps(-0.0f);
__m128 signs = _mm_and_ps(x, signmask); // save signs

// make all values positive
x = _mm_andnot_ps(signmask, x);

int k = 0;
int mask, oldmask = 0;

    __m128  z  = _mm_mul_ps(x, half);
    __m128  flags;
    __m128 kvec;
    // repeat halving           
    while (k < maxloops) {
                
        // make flag either 0 or 0.5 (this value is used as a multiplier later)
        flags = _mm_cmpgt_ps(z, f);  
        flags = _mm_mul_ps(_mm_and_ps(flags, multipliermask), one);
        // calculate k for each element
        kvec = _mm_add_ps(kvec,_mm_mul_ps(_mm_and_ps(flags, multipliermask), two));  
        // get mask value to control the loop
        mask = _mm_movemask_epi8((__m128i)z);
        // break loop when all needed done       
        if( mask == oldmask){
                           std::cout << "BREAK " << k << "\n";
            k--;
            break;
        }
        oldmask = mask;
        k++;
        // calculate new z values by flags
        z  = _mm_sub_ps(z, _mm_mul_ps(z, flags));
    }

    __m128  z2 = _mm_mul_ps(z, z);
    __m128  t  = _mm_div_ps(z, c2);
    __m128  p  = _mm_mul_ps(t, t);
            t  = _mm_div_ps(z2, c1);
            p  = _mm_mul_ps(p, _mm_sub_ps(t, one));
            p  = _mm_add_ps(one, p);
            p  = _mm_mul_ps(z, p);
            t  = _mm_div_ps(z, c2);
    __m128  q  = _mm_mul_ps(t, t); 
            t  = _mm_div_ps(z2, c3);
            q  = _mm_mul_ps(q, _mm_sub_ps(t, four));
            q  = _mm_add_ps(q, one);
        
    __m128  r  = _mm_div_ps(p, q);

    // double-angle identity
    __m128 tmp = r;
    __m128 multipliers;
    while (k>=0){  // release looped continuously if no condition check
        multipliers = _mm_and_ps(_mm_cmpgt_ps(kvec, half), one);
        tmp = _mm_mul_ps(_mm_div_ps(_mm_mul_ps(two, tmp), _mm_sub_ps(one, _mm_mul_ps(tmp,tmp))), multipliers);
        tmp = _mm_max_ps(_mm_sub_ps(_mm_setzero_ps(), tmp), tmp);
        r = _mm_max_ps(r, tmp);  
        kvec = _mm_sub_ps(kvec, multipliers);
        --k;
    }
    // restore signs
    r = _mm_xor_ps(signs,r);
    // finalize calculations and return values
    if (sine){
            __m128 res = _mm_div_ps(_mm_mul_ps(two, r), _mm_add_ps(one, _mm_mul_ps(r,r)));
            return res;
        }
        // cosine
        return _mm_div_ps(_mm_sub_ps(one, _mm_mul_ps(r, r)), _mm_add_ps(one, _mm_mul_ps(r,r)));
}

int main() {
    
    bool sine = true;
    float res[4] = { 0 };
    float in = 0.05;
    int maxloops = 10;
    if (std::abs(in) > M_PI/2.0){ sine = false;}

    __m128 x = _mm_set_ps(in, 1.31f, -0.23f, 0.79f);
    __m128 f = _mm_set_ps(0.5f, 0.25f, 0.5f, 0.5f);

    _mm_storeu_ps(res, sincos_sse(x, f, true, maxloops));
    
    std::cout << "\n\nsincos_sse  = " << res[3] << "  " << res[2] << "  " << res[1] << "  "<< res[0] << "  " << std::endl;    
    std::cout << "std::sin    = " << std::sin(x[3]) << "  " << std::sin(x[2]) << "  "<< std::sin(x[1]) << "  "<< std::sin(x[0]) << "  " << std::endl;
    
    std::cout << "difference  = ";
    for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--){
        if (sine){
            std::cout << std::sin(x[i]) - res[i] << "\t";
        }
        else{
            std::cout << std::cos(x[i]) - res[i] << "\t";
        }

    }
    
   
}
```

With outputs at [GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/z/qsjWsaPcK)

Here is the version based on Peter Cordes's suggestions.

https://godbolt.org/z/T177YYPPr (cleaned: https://godbolt.org/z/csK19EEP3 )

Comment: Wondering why gcc64 (13.2.) compiler option -O3 makes the function give wrong results now and then, depending on x and f values ... _kvec_ gets weird values like {4.5744e-41, 4.05647e+33, 4.5744e-41, 4.57162e+33} ... -O2 seem to work correctly.

Comment: This is not very good test when ran in browser but, by its results, there's not much difference in performance between these two implementations. Approx. rdtsc/val....
sincos_sse_jp() : 4.63614 , sincos_sse_pc() : 4.69075 . Though, both give lower  rdtcs/val result compared to std::sin()'s : 9.64479 . https://godbolt.org/z/bfE3njn7e . When tested in an old PC I got about 20% performance increase against std::sin() so, it's not huge improvement.